# How to return temp table result in postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I am using a temporary table in a function to save some results however I don't know how to return the table from the function. Ideally I would like to do everything in one query (i.e. not two queries: one for calling the function, the other to get data from the temp table).

Currently my `main_function()` is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_t CASCADE;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_t AS SELECT * FROM tbl_t limit 0;

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO temp_t ' || 'SELECT * FROM tbl_t limit 10';

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

And I am calling it like so:

```
SELECT * from main_function();
SELECT * from temp_t;
```

Again, the problem is that I don't actually want to call the second query. The first query should return the temp table as a result, however I cannot do this since the temp table is created in `main_function()` so it cannot be its return type.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside your main_function():

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM temp_t;
```

...if temp_t table consists of e.g. column1 (type integer), column2 (boolean) and column3 (varchar(100)), you should also define returned type as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function(column1 OUT integer, column2 OUT boolean, column3 OUT varchar(100)) RETURNS SETOF record AS
(...)
```

Another way is to define new data type:

```
CREATE TYPE temp_t_type AS (
    column1 integer,
    column2 boolean,
    column3 varchar(100)
);
```

That type can be returned by your functions in the same way as normal data types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function() RETURNS SETOF temp_t_type AS
(...)
```

...and return result from the function in the same way as mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you *need* a temporary table? Most of the time, there is a cheaper solution. Your example can simply be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function()
  RETURNS SETOF tbl_t AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM tbl_t LIMIT 10';

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You also don't need `EXECUTE` or even plpgsql for the simple case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function()
  RETURNS SETOF tbl_t AS
$BODY$

SELECT * FROM tbl_t LIMIT 10;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Never quote the language name. It's an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function() RETURNS void AS

use some like
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main_function() RETURNS TABLE(f1 int, f2 text) AS...