# Recurring future date at every 3 month after create date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am looking for a function in PostgreSQL which help me to generate recurring date after every 90 days from created date
for example: here is a demo table of mine.

```
id   date           name
1   "2020-09-08"    "abc"
2   "2020-09-08"    "xyz"
3   "2020-09-08"    "def"
```

**I need furure date like 2020-12-08, 2021-03-08, 2021-06-08, and so on**

Comment: You want 90 days or 3 months? Both will return different values

Answer (score 0):

First it's important to note that, if you happen to have a date represented as text, then you can convert it to a date via:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2017-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

So, if you happen to have a text as an input, then you will need to convert it to date. Next, you need to know that if you have a date, you can add days to it, like

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '90 day';
```

Now, you need to understand that you can use dynamic variables, like:

```
select now() + interval '1 day' * 180;
```

Finally, you will need a temporary table to generate several values described as above. Read more here: [How to return temp table result in postgresql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488859/how-to-return-temp-table-result-in-postgresql-function/35042736)

## Summary:

- create a function
- that generates a temporary table
- where you insert as many records as you like
- having the date shifted
- and converting text to date if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns a SETOF dates/timestamps. The below function takes 3 parameters: a timestamp, an interval, the num_of_periods desired. It returns num_of_periods + 1 timestamps, as it returns the original timestamp and the num_of_periods each the specified interval apart.

```
create or replace 
function generate_periodic_time_intervals
         ( start_date timestamp
         , period_length interval 
         , num_of_periods integer
         , out gen_timestamp timestamp
         )
  returns setof timestamp
  language sql 
  immutable strict
as $$
    select (start_date + n * period_length)::timestamp
      from generate_series(0,num_of_periods) gs(n)
$$;
```

For your particular case to timestamp/date as necessary. The same function would work for your case with the interval specified as '3 months' or of '90 days'. Just a note the interval specified can be any valid INTERVAL data type. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=180b352e957ba1cc8ee81467e89e79cb). It also demonstrates the difference between 3 months and 90 days.